# Implementing Code Highlighting

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, codehighlighter

I have a stack oriented programming language that I need to write a very simple editor for, with code highlighting. It would be preferable to do such with a `RichTextBox`

I have seen many code highlighting samples and demos, and nearly all of them require the entire `RichTextBox` to be refreshed `OnTextChanged`. This works for smaller code files, and even with slightly larger ones, if the scrollbar is correctly re-positioned, but the bigger the file gets, the greater the lag when trying to edit.

There's *got* to be a better way. Obviously, Visual Studio does it flawlessly...

So, what method should I use?

(Pseudocode or even just a general concept layout is fine for an answer)

Comment: Obviously they've written their own control, that handles everything, not using RichTextBox.

Comment: Oh, that might be a good method... although its probably a lot easier for them, since they have the source for `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` :P

Comment: hehe yes, *probably* they have ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scintilla is used in [a **lot**](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaRelated.html) of different editors. Notepad++ is one of them.

Here is a .Net wrapper: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to use the open-source [ICSharpCode.TextEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextEditorControl.aspx). This is a very rich text editor with support for customizable syntax highlighting and even intellisense. Among other features like line-numbers, error-highlighting, error-hinting, code-block-collapse and etc.

Examples of applications that use it are:

- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)
- [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really want to write your own, I used [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx), the editor from [SharpDevelop](http://sharpdevelop.net/)  for something similar, works pretty nice. It's WPF though, you didn;t say what UI technology you're on. You can even use it in commercial software with the license.

GJ